# spark sql string to timestamp missing milliseconds

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, milliseconds, format-string

Why is:

```
import spark.implicits._
  val content = Seq(("2019", "09", "11","17","16","54","762000000")).toDF("year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second", "nano")
  content.printSchema
  content.show
  content.withColumn("event_time_utc", to_timestamp(concat('year, 'month, 'day, 'hour, 'minute, 'second), "yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
    .withColumn("event_time_utc_millis", to_timestamp(concat('year, 'month, 'day, 'hour, 'minute, 'second, substring('nano, 0, 3)), "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"))
    .select('year, 'month, 'day, 'hour, 'minute, 'second, 'nano,substring('nano, 0, 3), 'event_time_utc, 'event_time_utc_millis)
    .show
```

missing the milliseconds?

```
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|year|month|day|hour|minute|second|     nano|substring(nano, 0, 3)|     event_time_utc|event_time_utc_millis|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|2019|   09| 11|  17|    16|    54|762000000|                  762|2019-09-11 17:16:54|  2019-09-11 17:16:54|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

for a format string of: `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS` which should include the milliseconds in `SSS` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: What is your spark version

Comment: 2.2.2 is my version of spark.

Comment: Okay, yes in spark <2.4 milliseconds conversation was not supported. Please check below answer for solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced similar problem,  Official [Document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_timestamp-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) says below line till **spark <2.4**:

> Convert time string to a Unix timestamp ***(in seconds)*** with a specified
>   format (see
>   [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html])
>   to Unix timestamp **(in seconds)**, return null if fail.

**Which means that it handles seconds only.**

[**Spark>= 2.4**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_timestamp-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) can handle `SSS` as well.

**Solution:** Below **UDF** will help to handle this scenario:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val getTimestampWithMilis: ((String , String) => Option[Timestamp]) = (input, frmt) => input match {
  case "" => None
  case _ => {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat(frmt)
    Try(new Timestamp(format.parse(input).getTime)) match {
      case Success(t) => Some(t)
      case Failure(_) => None
    }    
  }
}

val getTimestampWithMilisUDF = udf(getTimestampWithMilis)
```

For your Example:

```
val content = Seq(("2019", "09", "11","17","16","54","762000000")).toDF("year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second", "nano")
val df = content.withColumn("event_time_utc", concat('year, 'month, 'day, 'hour, 'minute, 'second, substring('nano, 0, 3)))
df.show
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+-----------------+
|year|month|day|hour|minute|second|     nano|   event_time_utc|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+-----------------+
|2019|   09| 11|  17|    16|    54|762000000|20190911171654762|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+-----------------+

df.withColumn("event_time_utc_millis", getTimestampWithMilisUDF($"event_time_utc", lit("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"))).show(1, false)
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+
|year|month|day|hour|minute|second|nano     |event_time_utc   |event_time_utc_millis  |
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+
|2019|09   |11 |17  |16    |54    |762000000|20190911171654762|2019-09-11 17:16:54.762|
+----+-----+---+----+------+------+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+

root
 |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hour: string (nullable = true)
 |-- minute: string (nullable = true)
 |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nano: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_time_utc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_time_utc_millis: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: OK. That was clear ;) but more maintenance & slower. I hoped for a better solution, but with my version of spark apparently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concat in this standard : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssss" (it ignores zeros, example : "762000000" as nano/milliseconds becomes "762")

```
youDataframe
.withColumn("dateTime_complete", 
concat_ws(" ", concat_ws("-", col("year"), col("month"), col("day")),
        concat_ws(":", col("hour"), col("minute"), concat_ws(".", col("second"), col("nano")))))
.withColumn("your_new_column", to_utc_timestamp(col("dateTime_complete"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss"))
```

Comment: Why will then: `.withColumn("your_new_column_ts", to_timestamp(col("dateTime_complete"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss"))
` be null?

Comment: As the input is UTC an additional conversion to UTC does not change the output, but seems to be unnecessary. Instead, NULL is returned.